# Guardar una variable en un botón sin caja de texto

Tags: c#

¿Como puedo guardar una variable en un botón y que al momento de darle click, este guarde la opción a la que se le dio click? por ejemplo estoy realizando una encuesta para un museo por medio de botones y el usuario tiene que seleccionar el tipo de visita(visita regular) y quiero que al seleccionar este botón, se registre(guarde) que se selecciono esa opción y así con las demás, ya que todas las preguntas son con botones, lo estoy realizando en C#, pero la verdad no tengo la mas minima idea de como hacer eso, espero alguien pueda ayudarme.

Comment: donde es que guardas la seleccion ? usas una base de datos. Porque las opciones son botones y no radiobutton ?

Comment: que tipo de desarrollo realizas? es web o desktop

Comment: podrías aclarar si es winforms o web? agrega también parte del código putualmente donde tienes problemas.

Comment: Apenas estoy iniciando la aplicación, pero la idea es que las selecciones se guarden en una base de datos, las opciones con botones para a aplicación en visual por medio de windows forms, ya que el museo es infantil y dicha aplicación tiene que ser muy gráfica y atractiva a los niños, es para desktop.

Answer (score 2):

Hay varias maneras de hacer lo que quieres (si es que lo entiendo bien, porque no está muy bien explicado, y asumiendo que hablamos de Winforms). Por un lado, podrias tener unas variables booleanas y en el evento del boton modificar estas variables con algo asi:

```
bool visitaguiada;
private void visitaguiadaButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    visitaguiada = !visitaguiada;
}
```

Pero en ese caso tambien tendrias que controlar que el boton reflejara visualmente su estado. Creo que la mejor solucion en tu caso es, en lugar de botones, utilizar controles `CheckBox` y cambiar la propiedad `Appearence`a `Button`. De esa manera, cuando quisieras validar el formulario solo tendrias que comprobar la propiedad `IsChecked` del `CheckBox`.

Espero que esto te ayude.

Answer (score 2):

Una posible solución es crear una `Lista` con los valores seleccionados guardando la propiedad `Text` del `botón` asumiendo que esta es (visita regular)

```
    /* Declaración de Variables */
    List<string> seleccion;
    Button btn;

    /* Creación e Inicialización , Constructor de tu Form */
    public Formulario()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        seleccion = new List<string>(); /* List*/
        /* Asignamos el  método MetodoClickGeneric al evento click de los botones*/
        btn1.Click += MetodoClickGeneric; 
        btn2.Click += MetodoClickGeneric;
        ....
    }

   /* Metodo */
   void MetodoClickGeneric(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            btn = sender as Button;/* Casting al objeto Sender a Boton */
            /* Verificamos si La Opción ya se Selecciono si no lo agregamos a la Lista*/
            if (seleccion.Contains(btn.Text.Trim().ToUpper()))
                MessageBox.Show("Ya Selecciono esta Opción");
            else
                seleccion.Add(btn.Text.Trim().ToUpper());
        }
```

> Hay algo Interesante aquí. al cerrar el programa los datos se perderán
>   para eso hay que persistir los datos(base de datos, archivos) en este
>   caso daré un ejemplo de archivo para guardar las opciones
>   seleccionadas , además tomar en cuenta que podría cambiar la opción de botones por RadioButton

```
  void Grabar()
    {
        using (System.IO.StreamWriter file =
        new System.IO.StreamWriter("Archivo.txt"))
        {
            file.WriteLine("OPCIONES SELECCIONADAS");
            foreach(string  entry in seleccion)
           {
                file.WriteLine(entry.ToUpper());

            }
        }
    }
```